# History.js rewrites location.hash value

Tags: jquery, history.js

I'm using HTML5 jQuery bundled [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) plugin. It's working fine, but i need to have ability to use links like (works fine without History.js)

```
http://website/url#popup=/url/some/more/params/
```

For a moment, if i will try to use it my hash page will be reloaded without hash - i've just tested this in environment with just History.js plugin (to ensure that is a History.js problem).

```
http://website/popup=/url/some/more/params/
```

But if i will try hash without "/" symbol, everything will be ok, location.hash will stay unchanged, no page reload will be made:

```
http://website/#popup=url
```

Problem is that i would like to use native urls in #popup parameter. 
It's easy to handle and displayed this way link will be clear to users, everyone will be able to share link after popup is opened.

Is it possible to disable such location.hash change and redirects? I really don't think that using links with special delimeres is good idea:

```
http://website/#popup=url:param:values
```

P.S. I've tried to apply encodeURIComponent() to popup url before adding it to location.hash, following url also removes hash and makes redirect:

```
http://website/#popup%3D%2Ftest%2Furl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL is not valid, forward slash should be %2F if it comes after the hash.

Furthermore, entering in the address bar

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953766/history-js-rewrites-location-hash-value#popup=eerste/tweede/derde`

Will create `#popup=eerste/tweede/derde` in location.hash, which is correct.

Seems to me you should file a bug report with the authors of History.js

Comment: Just tried to use link http://website/url#popup=%2Furl%2Fsome%2Fmore%2Fparams%2F in Chrome. Same result.